# Does the limit of $\frac{x}{y}$ depend on the direction we approach from?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, ratio

Consider $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$

Suppose we want to consider 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0} \frac{x}{y}
$$

Does this limit exist if we approach from different directions?

---

I figure if we approach from the horizontal axis, then for any $x$ the function will be very large.

**However**, if we approach such that $\frac{x}{y}=1$ at every point (i.e. if we approach along the line $y=x$ then shouldn't this limit exist (and $=1$??))

If that is true though... then wouldn't there be infinitely many limits depending on the line along which we approach (i.e. if we approach from $y=2x$, then the limit would be $.5$ etc)

Comment: If the limit exists, then it doesnt depend on the direction you approach from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using polar coordinates,

$$\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{\rho\cos\theta}{\rho\sin\theta}=\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\cot\theta.$$

This gives the value of the limit-when-coming-in-the-direction-$\theta$. (It does not exist when coming along the axis $x$, where $\theta=k\pi$.)

At the same time, this shows that

$$\lim_{x,y\to0}\frac xy$$ does not exist.

Comment: Aha! I was confused but the edited clarified it. Thank you. However, there are many (infinite?) limits depending on the direction then, though? (perhaps these are not called "limits" in typically terminology though?) (Also, I will accept this answer when it becomes possible)

Comment: @user106860: that's right. I think you may call them *directional limits*, just as there are *directional derivatives*

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially correct, but the terminology is that "the limit does not exist".

A limit is defined to exist if and only if the limit is the same from all directions. Proving that a limit does not exist requires only showing that if approached from 2 different directions it is not the same.